# How to ignore the text in a table?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have code that searches for ^p and replaces with ^p^p to insert a blank line between every paragraph.

I'd like this to not apply to paragraphs that are entirely bold (i.e. subheadings).

So "search for ^p and replace with ^p^p except for cases where the entire paragraph is bold".

I have a sort-of fix where I search for entirely bold paragraphs and delete the paragraph immediately following (which should just be a blank line after the search ^p and replace ^p^p.

The code below deletes the character immediately following an entirely bold paragraph.

```
Dim para As Paragraph
Dim searchRange As Range

Set searchRange = Selection.Range
searchRange.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End

For Each para In searchRange.Paragraphs
    If para.Range.Font.Bold = True And Not para.Range.Information(wdWithInTable) Then para.Range.Next.Delete
Next para
```

The problem is it does it in tables. So if I have a table header that is bold, it deletes the paragraph following, which will be the text in the next row of the table.

How can I get this bit of code to effectively check if a paragraph is entirely bold, and then delete the paragraph following it, UNLESS it is in a table?

Also if I could do the same but exempting if the following paragraph is a certain style, e.g. List Bullet.

Comment: Check whether `Selection.Information(wdWithinTable)` or `Range.Information(wdWithinTable) = True`. I'm sure this is a duplicate - the information is certainly already on the site. Also, you should include the relevant code (a [mcve] in the question. That's why I'm leaving this as a comment, not writing an answer.

Comment: The code is in the link above, as an answer from another user to my previous question. It uses Range.Information(wdWithInTable) = True, however I think that checks if the entirely bold paragraph is in a table (it deletes the following character which includes text in tables), which isn't what I need. I need it to check if the **following** paragraph is in a table and then move on to the next entirely bold paragraph without deleting anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the code you are already using. To work with the following paragraph use `para.Next`, as you are already doing for the deletion.

Simply change:

```
And Not para.Range.Information(wdWithInTable)
```

to:

```
And Not para.Next.Range.Information(wdWithInTable)
```

Comment: I get "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" when I try that

Comment: That's because you need to restrict the search range to not include the last paragraph of the document. Add this before the For loop: searchRange.MoveEnd wdParagraph, -1

Comment: Wonderful, that works, thank you very much! I've also managed to sort out the bit about the following paragraph's style (List Bullet).